# How to use JavaScript with HTML to change the background of a specific <div> based on a color <input>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Q: I am trying to specifically change a div to a chosen color, and not the entire body through JS

When using JS to utilize an input and change the background depending on a user-decided color, the only line of code I see/can get working is `document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;`

Is there a way to do, say, `document.(classNameForADiv).style.backgroundColor = color;`? I'm very new to HTML, CSS, and JS so any advice would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
         <div class="cell text">
            Background Color Picker:
        </div>
        <div class="cell js">
            <input type="color" id="color_value" name="color_value" value="Black">
            <!---DOUBLE (1 COLOR BOX 1 BUTTON)-->
            <button class="button two" type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
                Set Color:
            </button>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function changeBackground(){
  let color = document.getElementById('color_value').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

This changes the background of the entire Body tag, whereas I'm looking for a solution to change the background of a Div tag.

Comment: If there are any duplicates that I may have missed while I was checking for similar questions, please direct me!

Comment: get the div (using `div = document.getElementById('someid')`, or maybe `div = document.querySelector('some selector')`, etc etc) ... then `div.style.backgroundColor = color` - no idea which `div` you want to do this on, but the code should help

Comment: In addition, I think that taking a look at a tutorial about dom manipulation with js could help you. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp this is a nice resource

Comment: Edit: With the help of the other comments I've figured out what you meant, this has been incredibly helpful. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pick specific division for change division color.

```js
function changeBackground(){
  let color = document.getElementById('color_value').value;
  let division = document.getElementById("cell_text");
  division.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell text" id = "cell_text">
    Background Color Picker:
</div>
<br>
<div class="cell js">
   <input type="color" id="color_value" name="color_value" value="Black">
   <!---DOUBLE (1 COLOR BOX 1 BUTTON)-->
   <button class="button two" type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
        Set Color:
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the speedy reply. This helps me understand what my question was an even a little more with the use of 'let division.' Thanks!

Comment: @Matbart You most welcome. Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

change the color of div tag only.
(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor);

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Is there a way to do `document.(classNameForADiv).style.backgroundColor = color;` ?

**A:** Yes, it's called [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and it accepts a valid CSS selector. It will retrieve the first element in a page that matches the selector:

```
document.querySelector('.my-class').style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector(".my-class")` to grab the first element that has `my-class` as class. In your case like so:

```html
<div class="cell text">
  Background Color Picker:
</div>
<div class="cell js">
  <input type="color" id="color_value" name="color_value" value="Black">
  <!---DOUBLE (1 COLOR BOX 1 BUTTON)-->
  <button class="button two" type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
    Set Color:
  </button>
</div>
        
 <script>
    function changeBackground() {
      let color = document.getElementById("color_value").value;
      document.querySelector(".cell").style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
 </script>
```

**querySelector** allows to grab HTML elements with the same selectors as CSS, which can be really handy. If you wanna learn more about it, here is a great [ressource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 1):

Please check Updated your code

```js
function changeBackground(){
let color = document.getElementById('color_value').value;
document.getElementById('color-box').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
 <div class="cell text">
            Background Color Picker:
        </div>
        <div class="cell js">
            <input type="color" id="color_value" name="color_value" value="Black">
            <!---DOUBLE (1 COLOR BOX 1 BUTTON)-->
            <button class="button two" type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
                Set Color:
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <div id="color-box">
        THis is color box
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Then you have the specify the target div. I put below a div with ID output. That would change the color only in the div.

```js
function changeBackground(){
  
  let color = document.getElementById('color_value').value;  
  document.getElementById('output').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
#output {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
            Background Color Picker:
        </div>
        <div class="cell js">
            <input type="color" onchange="changeBackground()" id="color_value" name="color_value" value="Black">
            <!---DOUBLE (1 COLOR BOX 1 BUTTON)-->
            <button class="button two" type="button" onclick="">
                Set Color:
            </button>
        </div>

<div id="output">traget DIV</div>
```

Comment: Very good! This was exactly the answer to my question and you even added an example div to help out. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MatbartYou welcome! If you found it was helpful that would be nice if you except the answear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="cell text">
    Background Color Picker:
</div>
<div class="cell js" >
    <input type="color" id="color_value" name="color_value" value="Black">
    <!---DOUBLE (1 COLOR BOX 1 BUTTON)-->
    <button class="button two" type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">
        Set Color:
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    function changeBackground() {
        var color = document.getElementById("color_value").value;
            document.body.style.backgroundColor=color;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).